# How can I get all the values of a column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5229501/576767) question, what is the best way to get all the values of a single column in a MySQL database?

For instance, all values of:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers
```

Looking for a non-deprecated answer.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate for now, let's see how resolving it on the original question works, and if it doesn't, return to the solution of a new Q&A.

Comment: This was maybe a nicer and cleaner [awnser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047724/pdo-fetchall-array-to-one-dimensional) and look for [example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1055) in php docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Column FROM foo LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
var_dump(array_keys($array));
```

---

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(7960)
  [1]=>
  int(7972)
  [2]=>
  int(8028)
  [3]=>
  int(8082)
  [4]=>
  int(8233)
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this question and this answer. I am genuinely asking, because I see it was meant to be an FAQ and you have 7 upvotes, but the duplicate target has much better answer of yours.

Comment: @Dharman I wrote this new question after a discussion with PHP folks in the php chat about the duplicate link. We were not quite convinced that only writing an answer on the other question were to be sufficient, so we added both a new Q&A and an aswer to the other one. Time apparently prove us wrong.

Answer (score -3):

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die('DB Server Connection error'.mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die('DB Selection error'.mysqli_error());

$sql = 'SELECT name FROM Customers';

$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (0 < mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $resultArray[] = $data['name'];
    }
}
```