# Convert associative array of strings to flat array of integer (values only)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I cant figure out how to get Array 1 and make it look like Array 2 so that I can send it as parameters for my prepared statements method.

ARRAY 1: (what I currently have)

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "314" [0]=> string(3) "314" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "315" [0]=> string(3) "315" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "316" [0]=> string(3) "316" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "317" [0]=> string(3) "317" } }
```

ARRAY 2: What I'm trying to get it to be. (please ignore that 1 item is missing)

```
array(4) { [0]=> int(314) [1]=> int(315) [2]=> int(316) [3]=> int(317) }
```

I'm trying to accomplish this in PHP php7.1 if that matters.

I THINK this is enough information but if its not please let me know. I just didnt want to bog you down with all sorts of code and explanation that I'm not sure you need.

What I've tried so far (although possibly not properly):

```
$category_ids2 = array_values($category_ids);
```

Comment: The trick is in traversing the first array correctly. Check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684463/php-foreach-with-nested-array). Then you just need to get the individual values and populate your simple array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a function for extracting one column and another for converting to `integer`:

```
$category_ids = array_map('intval', array_column($category_ids, 'id'));
```

Without `array_column`:

```
$category_ids = array_map(function($v) { return (int)$v['id']; }, $category_ids);
```

However, this looks suspiciously like database results.  If so, then just build the array the way you want when fetching the results.  Also, using the `fetch` `assoc` of your database library would eliminate the `0` index in each array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. you are 100% correct that it is database result, but being very new to php in general, and even newer to PDO, i'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do the query without post process of converting with PDO. I will try and do more research on that though since I now know it seems to be possible. thank you so much :).

Comment: With your  direction I was able to figrue out how to do it directly from the query. Thank you so much :D.  Answer can be found here for those interested. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047724/pdo-fetchall-array-to-one-dimensional

Comment: Sorry, was my first post wasn't aware of marking them. I THINK I have done so now.  (If that is what the check mark is)

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [['id' => '1', '0' => '1'], 
      ['id' => '314', '0' => '314'],
      ['id' => '315', '0' => '315'],
      ['id' => '316', '0' => '316'],
      ['id' => '317', '0' => '317']];

echo "<pre>";

$ids = array_column($array, 'id');


unset($ids['0']); 
var_dump($ids);

$integerIDs = array_map('intval', $ids);

var_dump($integerIDs);
```

Explanation:

1. you should use `array_column` to get ids http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php
2. then unset if position zero is not required
3. `array_map('intval', $ids);` each and every values will be converted into `int`

Answer (score 0):

First use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to flatten the array. Then combine [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
 with [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to cast the strings to integers. All together:

```
$category_ids2 = array_map('intval', array_column($category_ids, 'id'));
```